# Sound not playing in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javasound

Here is the code for class SoundTest:

---

```
package code;


import java.io.File;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;


public class SoundTest {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        File sound = new File("main//Sounds//open1.wav");
        playSound(sound);
    }

    public static void playSound(File f)
    {
        try {

            File file = f;
            if(file.exists())
            {
                AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(audio);
                clip.start();
                //clip.close();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Can't find file");
            }


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Didn't work!");
        }
    }
}
```

---

When I run it, there are no errors or exceptions, and it never says "Can't find file" or "Didn't work!".  But I don't hear a sound.  Do I have to change some sort of setting in Eclipse to make the sound audible, or am I doing something wrong?  I'm pretty sure the sound file is located in the right place.

Comment: Does the log say Can't find file ?

Comment: No.  It runs completely fine, just can't hear sound.  I think it has to do with Eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not eclipse problem. File is being opened and played by java, but even before that audio clip completes playing, the program is getting terminated - Meaning java program is not waiting for the clip to complete playing

Your method is missing one single line of code to give you what you want, see below

`Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000);`

So, after adding this line your code should look like this and you will hear your music

```
    AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audio);
    clip.start();
    Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000);
```

Comment: Adding a bit to the explanation: the audio thread is a "daemon". Unlike regular threads, daemon threads do not hold an application open. Once your program is in a state where it stays open, the Thread.sleep command will no longer be needed.